# unable to initialize the chrome driver in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm setting up the selenium automation tasks in a new machine, so when i try to start the chrome browser, I'm getting the exception in the main method

Here is my java class

```
package POMs;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class AMCDaeralogin {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        setup();
    }
    
    
    public static void setup() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.http.factory", "jdk-http-client");
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
    
}
```

and here is the exception that i received

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.of(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)'
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.AddHasCasting.getAdditionalCommands(AddHasCasting.java:38)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver$ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.getExtraCommands(ChromeDriver.java:99)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver$ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:94)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:50)
    at POMs.AMCDaeralogin.setup(AMCDaeralogin.java:19)
    at POMs.AMCDaeralogin.main(AMCDaeralogin.java:12)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey just use the below line codes.

```
WebDriver driver=new chromeDriver();
```

if you are using Selenium version 4.6.0 above, not required to setup the browser path and all.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, the issue is something not right with my maven project and i created a new project it's working fine now

Answer (score 0):

Use latest Selenium version 4.10.X and replace setUp method with this.
Latest Selenium does not require to perform the System.Set Property

```
public static void setup() {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, the issue is something not right with my maven project and i created a new project it's working fine now